# How to email users the plain text password that has been encrypted with Sha512?

Tags: xampp

I Need To Make A Forgot For My Private Server (AQW)

I Make A Database And The Name Of the Database is Meh . In The Meh Database I Put meh_users
with :

- username
- password

When You Create A Account The Password Will Become Sha512 To Prevent Sqli Injecting of it . Like this : `F544FB304E4A24CDE`

- Age
- Sex
- Email

That is why I want to build "forgot Password" functionality.  I want to send the password  and username to Yahoo or Gmail. I want to decrypt the Sha512 password into plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Sha512 is hashing, not encryption, so it's irreversible.

A solution to this problem is that you can generate a new password, send it to the user in an email and store the hashed version in the database.

Comment: ohhh ... ok . what hash i gonna use sir ?/ ..  ~

Comment: sha512 i only used ! can i use Md5 ?